# mysql jdbc driver установить fetch size

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Mysql база состоит из 2 000 записей, я хочу получать данные частями, для этого согласно [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) выполнил следующий код:

```
 Statement statement = connection.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
 java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test");
        while (res.next())
            System.out.println(res.getInt(1));
```

Однако запрос к базе происходит один.Это видно в логах.

Answer (score 2):

Запрос в таком случае всегда будет один. Логика работы `setFetchSize` примерно следующая:

- устанавливается соединение с БД;
- выдаётся запрос на выборку;
- движок БД производит подготовительную работу и выдаёт клиенту требуемое число записей, сохраняя курсор;
- если клиент потребовал ещё данные, движок выдаёт их, опять сохраняя курсор;
- если данные закончились или клиент сказал "хватит!", движок уничтожает курсор, чистит память и рвёт соединение.

Несколько запросов в таком случае выдаваться не может, поскольку это может привести к неправильной выдаче. Запрос один, но если он будет "разорван" на несколько, то между ними могут пройти другие запросы на обновление, что изменит данные и, как следствие, некоторые строки могут быть выданы дважды, а некоторые пропущены.

Comment: пробую логировать работу mysql - 
SET GLOBAL log_output="FILE"
SET GLOBAL general_log_file="Path/File"
SET GLOBAL general_log='ON'
но курсоров там не видно(

Comment: Вот тут ничего не подскажу. Не знаю, умеет ли MySQL логировать такое. К тому же, я указал **примерную** логику, конкретная реализация может работать по-другому.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch size про другое. Это сколько за раз драйвер выгребает строк, чтоб потом кормить их после вызова rs.next(). Если ставите, например 10, то он будет после каждых 10 строк бегать в БД и тащить следующую пачку. Если же поставить 2000, то он подождет пока БД наберет 2000 строк результата и выкачает их все сразу. Но осторожно, память скорее всего будет тоже аллоцирована под все 2000, причем "с запасом".

Иными словами, если запрос простой и Вы просто вычитываете данные в какой-то кеш - надо ставить fetchSize побольше (но без фанатизма), но если запрос сложный и то лучше ставить fetchSize поменьше. В последнем случае ваша программа их начнет раньше обрабатывать, не станет ждать когда у БД наберется результат на большой fetchSize.

Правда для mysql подобная регулировка не актуальна, судя по документации там печалька и есть только два положения - вкл/выкл. Либо по одной строке, либо сразу всё.

Comment: ну и ава =\     лол

Comment: да, икс дэ - рофол.